# Revisions fail to compare correctly when the language is defined

Tags: bug

In this revision

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12/revisions

on number 12 (last one right now on top) the user just adds this line:

```
<!-- language: lang-csharp -->
```

And it's not only showing it as different, but it fails to show all the rest of the code as the same on the "inline" and "side by side" views.

It works correct only on "side by side Markdown".

My only point is that I take too many hours trying to see what the user changes, and line by line I look the code until understand what's going on.